# What is a "Manager" in django?

Tags: python, django

I have read the definition in the official Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/), and I am still confused by what a `Manager` does.

The documentation says that they allow you to operate on database tables/models, but I still don't understand this.

Can someone explain managers and their role to me? An answer with an example would be preferable.

Comment: `Managers` are quite a complex django class, if you're new to programming I'd stick with the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) until you're more confident with code.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A manager is usually something hidden away from django programmers that django uses to interface between `model` code and the database backend.

When you query the django ORM, you do so through calls to

```
from my_app.models import MyModel

mms = MyModel.objects.all()
```

In this case, the `objects` part of the function is what is returned by the manager. If you wanted MyModel to only ever get `blue` `MyModel` instances (the database might contain `red` models too) then you could create a manager and hack your model thus

```
class BlueManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(BlueManager, self).get_query_set().filter(colour='Blue')

class MyModel(models.Model):
     colour = models.CharField(max_length=64)
     blue_objects = BlueManager()
```

and calling

```
MyModel.blue_objects.all()
```

would only return objects with `colour` as `blue`. Note, this is a very poor way to filter models!

One would usually need to modify a `Manager` interface if they were going to modify the `QuerySet`s that a manager would usually return or if you needed to add "table" level queries (rather than regular django "row" level). The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) for managers is quite complete and contains several examples.

Comment: For extra credit, read the source code on github. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/manager.py

Answer (score 12):

Manager is some kind of 'gate' between application and database. One of nice thing is that you can define you own base queryset for model. For example: if you have model 'Book' with 'availability' field, you can prepare your own queryset, which filters specific kind of availability type:

models.py:

```
class AvailableBookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(AvailableBookManager, self).get_query_set().filter(availability=1)

class Book(models.Model):
   (...)#fields definition
 
   objects = models.Manager() #default manager
   available_objects = AvailableBookManager() #own manager
```

and now you can use like this:

```
books = Book.available_objects.all()
```

instead of using:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(available=1)
```

Answer (score 10):

### Definition

From the docs:

> A Manager is a Django class that provides the interface between database query operations and a Django model.

In other words, in a Django model, the manager is the interface that interacts with the database. For example, when you want to retrieve objects from your database, you need to construct a `QuerySet` via a `Manager` on your model class.

By default, the manager is available through the `Model.objects` property. This manager is the `django.db.models.Manager`. However, it is very simple to extend it and change the default manager.

### Custom managers

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers):

> You can use a custom Manager in a particular model by extending the base Manager class and instantiating your custom Manager in your model.

There are two reasons you might want to customize a Manager (none of them are exclusive):

1. to add extra Manager methods
2. to modify the initial QuerySet the Manager returns

#### Example: adding extra methods to a Manager

```py
from django.db import models

class DocumentManager(models.Manager):
    def pdfs(self):
        return self.filter(file_type='pdf')

    def smaller_than(self, size):
        return self.filter(size__lt=size)


class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    size = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

    objects = DocumentManager()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

#### Example: modifying the initial QuerySet the Manager returns

```py
from django.db import models


class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(first_name__startswith='M')

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

    objects = AuthorManager()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

#### Example: multiple managers at the same time

It is possible to have multiple managers for the same model.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Length

class BookTitleManager(models.Manager):
    def short_titles(self):
        return self.annotate(length=Length('title')).filter(length__lte=20)

    def long_titles(self):
        return self.annotate(length=Length('title')).filter(length__gt=20, length__lte=30)
    
    def very_long_titles(self):
        return self.annotate(length=Length('title')).filter(length__gt=30)

    def starts_with(self, letter):
        return self.filter(title__startswith=letter)


class BookPagesManager(models.Manager):
    def small_books(self):
        return self.filter(pages__lt=200)
    
    def medium_books(self):
        return self.filter(pages__gte=200, pages__lt=300)
    
    def large_books(self):
        return self.filter(pages__gte=300, pages__lte=500)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pages = models.IntegerField()

    objects = models.Manager()
    titles = BookTitleManager()
    sizes = BookPagesManager()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.title} by {self.author}'
```

In the previous code sample, there are 3 managers: the default `models.Manager`, `BookTitleManager` and `BookPagesManager` assigned to `objects`, `titles` and `sizes` respectively.

The problem with the previous managers is that you cannot chain them as follows:

```py
>>> Book.titles.long_titles().starts_with('P')
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'starts_with'
```

#### Example: Custom manager and queryset (chains are allowed)

If you want to chain methods defined in managers, you should define a custom QuerySet as follows:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Length


class AuthorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def long_first_name(self):
        return self.annotate(length=Length("first_name")).filter(length__gte=10)

    def short_last_name(self):
        return self.annotate(length=Length("last_name")).filter(length__lte=10)


class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return AuthorQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def long_first_name(self):
        return self.get_queryset().long_first_name()

    def short_last_name(self):
        return self.get_queryset().short_last_name()


class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

    objects = AuthorManager()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

#### Example: Custom queryset used as manager

When defining just custom `QuerySets` in the manager, it is possible to simply extend the `QuerySet` and set it as the manager.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Length


class PublisherQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def long_name(self):
        return self.annotate(length=Length("name")).filter(length__gte=15)

    def long_address(self):
        return self.annotate(length=Length("address")).filter(length__gte=25)

    def country_starts_with(self, letter):
        return self.filter(country__startswith=letter)


class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = PublisherQuerySet.as_manager() # uses QuerySet as Manager

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

#### Also to keep in mind

- If you want to use `objects` as a field name, or if you want to use a name other than `objects` for the Manager, you can rename it on a per-model basis. To rename the Manager for a given class, define a class attribute of type models.Manager() on that model.

```py
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    size = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

    stuff = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

In the previous code sample, calling `Document.objects` will generate an `AttributeError` exception because the default manager has been renamed, what will work now is `Document.stuff`.

- Managers are accessible only via model classes, rather than from model instances, to enforce a separation between “table-level” operations and “record-level” operations.
- If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this Manager is named `FOO_set`, where `FOO` is the source model name, lowercased.