# When should I create methods in model

Tags: python, django

I have model Post and i'm making querysets like this in view

```
user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=user)
blocked_users = user.blocked.all()
posts_except_blocked = Post.objects.exclude(author__in=blocked_users).order_by('-pub_date')
```

and a few similar. But i recognized that I can put this into model class as @staticmethod and now it's looking

```
@staticmethod
def get_posts_except_blocked(user):
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=user)
    blocked_users = user.blocked.all()
    return Post.objects.exclude(author__in=blocked_users).order_by('-pub_date')
```

Should I put every queries like this to model?
I have there in views method

```
def create_notifications(post):
    for word in post.content_post.split():
        if '@' in word:
            user_to_notificate = CustomUser.objects.get(username=word[1:])
            TalkAbout(where=post, _from=post.author, to=user_to_notificate).save()
```

I'm calling it after save post form to create notifications. Can this be in views or maybe I need to put it in Post class too? Is it possible to call this function automaticly after creating post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can put class related methods into Model class. Or you can use Model Manager.

> A Manager is the interface through which database query operations are provided to Django models. At least one Manager exists for every model in a Django application. The way Manager classes work is documented in Making queries; this document specifically touches on model options that customize Manager behavior.

[Manager in Django offical doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#:~:text=A%20Manager%20is%20the%20interface,options%20that%20customize%20Manager%20behavior.)

[What is Manager in Djnago stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689237/what-is-a-manager-in-django)

Comment: Thank you, i will check it, but what with create_notifications method i views? Can i have methods like it in views if it doesn't response anything to template?

Comment: You can use post_save signal when new post is saved you can send notifications.